# Why font quality differ from the PSD in HTML

Tags: fonts, xhtml, psd

When I convert PSDs to XHTML+CSS, the most common problem I always feel is the crispiness of fonts edges & the size unit.

In Photoshop the font size unit is pt, and in css its px. Now the smoothness in Photoshop is awesome but when I get it to XHTML, i can't achieve the same smoothness neither for common fonts like myrid  pro nor for rare fonts for which I use @font-face property.

Now recently I converted a PSD to XHTML, the font used was GothamHTF, I used @font-face to make this font available on the site, but the issue is I can't achieve the same quality as I did in Photoshop for same text, font, size.

Did anyone face the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has an engine in place for rendering typefaces. The five browsers also have an engine in place for rendering typefaces.

These engines are different and as a result, typefaces are not always displayed the same (or very good sometimes).

The best way to ensure quality control in select places is to use an image of your headline or text. Otherwise, it is best to understand that one font does not display the same across all screen media.

Answer (score 0):

It is not convenient to use images as titles or pieces of text. In this way google or any other search engine will not index the text you're using as an image. NOT SEO FRIENDLY.